# MYSQL Join returns duplicate column name

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL and have the following challenge, I have a table on the left that has products assigned to a single company and denoted by a ref_id (it comes from another table, and I have simplified it for sake of question) and I have a master list.  I want to compare all the products for company "A" against the master list and show all the products company A has not subscribed to. I am using JOIN and end up getting duplicate column names which throws my PHP program off. Here is what I have tried several syntax for UNION, RIGHT JOIN, LEFT JOIN and NOT operators, and the below is the closest I have gotten, however I am getting duplicate column names and I only need the last table with the last 2 columns.   Please advise.

```
mysql> select ref_id, product_id, short_name from ap_company_product order by ref_id, product_id;
+--------+------------+------------+
| ref_id | product_id | short_name |
+--------+------------+------------+
|      2 | 10         | product 10 |
|      2 | 11         | product 11 |
|      2 | 12         | product 12 |
|      2 | 15         | product 15 |
|      2 | 17         | product 17 |
|      2 | 21         | product 21 |
|      3 | 11         | product 11 |
|      3 | 13         | product 13 |
|      3 | 17         | product 17 |
|      3 | 20         | product 20 |
+--------+------------+------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

THE MAIN LIST

mysql> select  product_id, short_name from ap_company_product_list;
+------------+-------------+
| product_id | short_name  |
+------------+-------------+
| 10         | product 10  |
| 11         | product 11  |
| 12         | product 12  |
| 13         | product 13  |
| 14         | product 14  |
| 15         | product 15  |
| 16         | product 16  |
| 17         | product 17  |
| 18         | product 18  |
| 19         | product 19  |
| 20         | product 20  |
| 21         | product 21  |
| 22         | product 22  |
+------------+-------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)


Another SQL which is the actual results I need

SELECT  aa.product_id as product_id, aa.short_name as short_name, aa.ref_id as ref_id, bb.product_id as product_id, bb.short_name as short_name FROM (select ref_id, product_id, short_name from ap_company_product where ref_id=2) aa  RIGHT OUTER JOIN ap_company_product_list bb ON aa.product_id = bb.product_id where aa.product_id is NULL;
+------------+------------+--------+------------+------------+
| product_id | short_name | ref_id | product_id | short_name |
+------------+------------+--------+------------+------------+
| NULL       | NULL       |   NULL | 13         | product 13 |
| NULL       | NULL       |   NULL | 14         | product 14 |
| NULL       | NULL       |   NULL | 16         | product 16 |
| NULL       | NULL       |   NULL | 18         | product 18 |
| NULL       | NULL       |   NULL | 19         | product 19 |
| NULL       | NULL       |   NULL | 20         | product 20 |
| NULL       | NULL       |   NULL | 22         | product 22 |
+------------+------------+--------+------------+------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Can you not use some other alias??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this:

```
SELECT  bb.product_id as product_id, bb.short_name as short_name FROM (select ref_id, product_id, short_name from ap_company_product where ref_id=2) aa  RIGHT OUTER JOIN ap_company_product_list bb ON aa.product_id = bb.product_id where aa.product_id is NULL;
```

BTW, I would prefer this one:

```
SELECT product_id, short_name FROM ap_company_product_list WHERE product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM ap_company_product);
```

Comment: Thank you so much your solution worked well, I went with your prefered solution, much simpler (just needed a closing prentices at the end).  It looks like I had over complicated my life and gone down the rabbit whole.  Thank you so much Ben.

Comment: @user2679455 No problem at all. SQL seems hard and deep to me even now.

Comment: By the way the prefered SQL was missing one WHERE parameter at the last result set, I changed it to   SELECT product_id, short_name FROM ap_company_product_list WHERE product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM ap_company_product WHERE ref_id=2);

Comment: @user2679455 Ah that's it. Fixed.